# I am getting a pointer being free but not allocated error when running make, make test in putty

Tags: c++

I am very new to object oriented programming, pointer use and allocating memory in C++.  I am working on an assignment for class and initially I had it pass the first three tests listed below by having an array, grade_array, that in the addScore function looked like grade_array[count -1] = grade.  Then it would be used in the mean function.

I know this is not the correct way to go about this because I was getting seg faults, so I know I need to have an array, then create a new array (twice the size) that allocates more memory so that I can put the values of the first one into the new one, and then delete to not get memory leaks.  The real problem I am having is I do not know if I am even close to correct on the way I am doing this.  The error I am getting:

```
 Running cxxtest tests (5 tests)testrunner(85436) malloc: *** error for object 0x107a87970: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
make: *** [test] Abort trap: 6
```

I have seen a lot of people having similar problems and posting about them on this very site I just cannot seem to fix mine.  I saw that it could be that I made a new pointer and tried to them have them point to the same thing so when one deletes the other has nothing to delete or that my initializer is wrong as it doesn't do much.  Like I said, very new to the topic so sorry if I have a million questions and so many errors. I have spent a lot of time on this already and was hoping I could maybe get some advice before I waste more time, thanks in advance!

#### Gradebook.h

```
#ifndef GRADEBOOK_H
#define GRADEBOOK_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Gradebook {
public:
  Gradebook();

  Gradebook(const string&  filename);

  Gradebook(const Gradebook& that);

  virtual ~Gradebook();

  void initCount();


  void addScore(double grade);

  double getScoreAt(int i);

  int getCount(int i);

  string getSourceFile();

  double getMean(); // change back to double

  double getMin();

  double getMax();

  double getMedian();

  double getStdDev();

  int scoresInRange(double low, double high);
private:
  string filename;
  int* grade_array;
  int new_size;
  int count;
  int count_tracker;
  int* grade_point;
};

#endif
```

#### Gradebook.cpp

```
void Gradebook::initCount(){
  count = 0;
}

Gradebook::Gradebook() {

}

Gradebook::Gradebook(const string&  filename) : filename(filename) {
  //this->filename = filename; // i beleive that filename(filename) does this line
  //grade_array = new int[this->getCount(0) +1];
}
Gradebook::Gradebook(const Gradebook& that) {

}

Gradebook::~Gradebook() {
  for ( int i = 0; i < this->getCount(0); i ++){
    delete &grade_array[i];
  }
  delete grade_array;
}

void Gradebook::addScore(double grade) {
  int count_tracker = this->getCount(1); //number of elements in array currently
  // grade_array = new int[count_tracker ];
  // grade_array = new int[1]; // grade_array is just a *array
  grade_array[count_tracker -1 ] = grade; // array[0] is first not array[1]
  new_size = count_tracker * 2;
  int* new_array = new int[new_size];
  for (int i = 0; i < count_tracker ; i++) {
    new_array[i]  = grade_array[i];
  }
  delete[] grade_array;
  grade_array = new_array;
  count_tracker = new_size;
}


double Gradebook::getScoreAt(int i) {
  return grade_array[i];
}

int Gradebook::getCount(int i) {
  if (i == 1){
    count = count + 1;
  }
    else{
      //don't want to add to the actual count
    }
  return count;
}

string Gradebook::getSourceFile() {
  //ifstream foo;

  //foo.open(filename);


  return filename;
}

double Gradebook::getMean() {
  double mean = 0;
  count_tracker = this->getCount(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < count_tracker  ; i++){
    //mean = (*(&(grade_array[i])- (bit_count))) +  mean;
     mean = grade_array[i] + mean;
   }
   return (mean/count_tracker);
}
```

#### GradebookTest.h

```
#ifndef GRADEBOOK_TEST_H
#define GRADEBOOK_TEST_H

#include <Gradebook.h>

#include <cxxtest/TestSuite.h>

class GradebookTest : public CxxTest::TestSuite {
public:

  void testDefaultConstructor(){
    string filename = "data1.txt";
    Gradebook a(filename);
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS("data1.txt"  , a.getSourceFile());
  }

  void testAddOne() {
    Gradebook gb;
    gb.initCount();
    gb.addScore(110);
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(120, gb.getScoreAt(1));
    TS_ASSERT_DELTA(110, gb.getMean(), 0.001);
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(4, gb.getCount(0) );
  }

  void testAddMultiple() {
    Gradebook gb;
    gb.addScore(75);
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(1, gb.getCount(0) );
    gb.addScore(85);
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(2, gb.getCount(0));
    TS_ASSERT_DELTA(85, gb.getMean(), 0.001);
  }

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is wrong

```
for ( int i = 0; i < this->getCount(0); i ++){
    delete &grade_array[i];
}
```

You don't need this for loop since you only allocate memory for `grad_array`. One `delete grade_array;` is enough.

Comment: thank you I think you are right.  Now I just need to find the other 700 errors.

Comment: Oh, no that doesn't fix the problem.